# how to close StreamWriter object

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, csv, streamwriter

I have one problem in my application. I need to create two CSV files from the two SQL query results. I created that one. I'm using `StreamWriter` to write the data into the CSV files.

My problem is first query result also written into the second file. I used `StreamWriter.Close()` and am still seeing the same behavior in the output.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false))
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I you write to two files, you should create two separate StreamWriters. Don't reuse the same.

Comment: I need to reuse that streamwriter. Is there any possible way

Comment: "I need to reuse that streamwriter." No, you really don't.

Comment: @StefanEdwards please explain why you need to reuse the `StreamWriter`.  There is no reason you need to reuse it unless it is a strange requirement of your project.  Some context as to why would be useful.

Comment: @StefanEdwards also, the example code is only showing you writing 1 file.  Please show some real code as to how you are re-using it to write to 2 different files.

Comment: @StefanEdwards, do I correctly understand that you want to write result of 2-nd query to 2-nd file and result of 1-st query to 1-st file and to 2-nd as well?

Comment: @aleksy.berezan No I need to write each sql query result into separate file

Comment: I got answer. I forgot to clear the datatable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure that a `StreamWriter` (or in fact, any `IDisposable` resource) is closed is to use the `using` statement where it is possible. Here is how:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\output\file1.csv")) {
    foreach (IDataReader row in myQueryResults) {
        writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", row.GetString(0), row.GetString(1), row.GetString(2));
    }
}
```

Once the scope of the `using` statement ends, normally or through an exception, the `writer` is closed automatically.

Comment: Still I'm facing the same problem

Comment: And are you sure that the 'other' call is using a filename different from @"c:\output\file1.csv" ???

Comment: I created two separate StreamWriter for each file. but still I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @StefanEdwards Are you sure that you are passing different `strFilePath` values there?.. Try seeing what's going on in the debugger.